# monitoring file changes in racket (like tail -f)

Tags: file, racket, change-tracking

I would like to implement a "tail -f" like behavior in Racket. That is, I would like to read from a file, and when I hit the end, be able making something like a "blocking" `(read-line file)`, that shall return when some other process appends a line to *file*.
I tried synchronizing with `(read-line-evt file)` but, if I am at the end of *file*, instead of blocking until other data is available, it returns immediately.
Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that you have any way to avoid polling the file.

Note that all of Racket's input functions consider `eof` a value that should be returned when it reaches the end of the input stream -- so all of the events immediately return that when the end is reached.  At least I don't see anything that looks like a "wait until *some* input is ready, not `eof`".

In any case, you also have the ffi, if you know about some system call that triggers a callback instead of polling the file.  AFAICT, the linux source code for `tail` uses inotify, so you might be able to use an old package that interfaces that from racket called [mzfam](http://planet.racket-lang.org/display.ss?package=mzfam.plt&owner=jao).  (But it's pretty old and might need some update work.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know when Racket added [file system change events](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html#%28part._filesystem-change%29), but I suspect it was since this question was asked many years ago. Now you can wait on such an event and see if you can read another line (It's not fine grained enough to tell specifically that more data was appended to the file, just that something changed about it.)

An example of a basic `tail -f` like program to demonstrate [`file-system-change-evt`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Filesystem.html#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._filesystem-change-evt%29%29):

```lisp
;;; tail.rkt
#lang racket/base
(require racket/list racket/port)

;;; Some utility functions and macros

;; Like take but return the list if it's less than n elements long
;; instead of raising an error
(define (take* list n)
  (with-handlers ([exn:fail:contract? (lambda (e) list)])
    (take list n)))

;; Repeat body forever until a break is received
(define-syntax-rule (forever body ...)
  (with-handlers ([exn:break? (lambda (e) (void))])
    (let loop ()
      body ...
      (loop))))

;; Display the last N lines of a file. Could be more efficient, but
;; this part's not the point...
(define (display-last-lines port n)
  (for-each displayln
            (reverse
             (for/fold ([lines '()])
                       ([line (in-lines port)])
               (take* (cons line lines) n)))))

;; Wait for the file's status to change and try to read lines when it does.
(define (follow-tail file)
  (call-with-input-file file
    (lambda (port)
      (display-last-lines port 10)
      (forever
       (sync (filesystem-change-evt file))
       (for ([line (in-lines port)])
         (displayln line))))))


(module+ main
  (unless (= (vector-length (current-command-line-arguments)) 1)
    (displayln "Usage: racket tail.rkt FILENAME" (current-error-port))
    (exit 1))

  (follow-tail (string->path (vector-ref (current-command-line-arguments) 0))))
```

---

After being inspired by this question and Eli's mention of [`inotify`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) in his answer, and seeing that there *still* wasn't a Racket package to provide access to it (I think the standard file system change code uses it internally, but it's not exposed at any low level to users), I [wrote it myself](https://docs.racket-lang.org/inotify/index.html). A version of the core tail function from above using it:

```lisp
(require inotify)
(define (follow-tail file)
  (call-with-input-file file
    (lambda (port)
      (display-last-lines port 10)
      (call-with-inotify-instance
       `((,file (IN_MODIFY)))
       (lambda (inotify wds)
         (forever
          (sync inotify)
          (for ([line (in-lines port)])
            (displayln line))))))))
```